# XNA: How to make background stay in background?

Tags: c#, xna

I thought that the draw method would draw stuff Front to back, so that the first things to be drawn in the code would be in the front, and the last would be in the front.
So, I'm trying to draw a tile background from a array, but some of it is in front of everything else, and some other parts are behind everything else. How do I fix this?

My draw code:

```
   protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(BackColor );

        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack,BlendState.AlphaBlend,null,null,null,null,m_Camera.Transform(graphics.GraphicsDevice ));

        Draw1();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

This is the draw method

```
    public void Draw1()
    {

        DrawText();
        topwall.Draw(spriteBatch);
        bottomwall.Draw(spriteBatch);
        for (int i = 0; i < wallsize; ++i)
        {

            //new GameObject(Tech[i].texture, Tech[i].Position );

            Tech[i].Draw(spriteBatch);
        }
        Door1.Draw(spriteBatch);
        Door2.Draw(spriteBatch);
        //playerOne.Draw(spriteBatch);
        //playerTwo.Draw(spriteBatch);
        ball.Draw(spriteBatch);
        drawdirt();
        spriteBatch.End();
    }
```

This draws the background

```
    public void drawdirt()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < world.GetUpperBound(0); ++i)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < world.GetUpperBound(1); ++n) { world[i, n].Draw(spriteBatch); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If it's at all possible, you should try to draw your sprites in back-to-front order in code, rather than relying on sorting. It would also be considerably better style to end your sprite batch in the same method that you begin it.

Answer (score 3):

No, by default SpriteBatch draws in the order of your draw calls (intuitively enough). Whatever you draw first gets drawn first, and whatever you draw last gets drawn last, on top of everything else. So you want to draw your background elements first, then the entities, then the UI, etc.

Alternatively, you can specify a layer depth on each [draw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433989.aspx) call and then use a custom sorting mode by specifying [SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritesortmode.aspx) on the call to SpriteBatch.Begin(). The layer depth is a real from 0 to 1, with 0 being the front and 1 being the back.

Comment: Note that this ordering only applies within the one batch begin/end block. Subsequent blocks will be drawn over the top no matter the depth specified.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the order in which objects are drawn by using the `SpriteSortMode` property before `SpriteBatch.Begin()` is called.

Further reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritesortmode.aspx